# Non-abelian group, where torsion elements form subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, torsion-groups

We proved in the lectures, that for an abelian group, the torsion elements (elements of finite order) form a subgroup.
I also found an example for a non abelian group, where the torsion elements do not form a subgroup.
Now I am wondering: Is there a non abelian group G, for which the torsion elements form a non trivial subgroup?
So where they are not only the neutral element and not the whole group.

Comment: There's the trivial example of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times X$ for $X$ nonabelian and torsion-free.

Comment: In any non-abelian *nilpotent* group the torsion set is a **normal** subgroup...